# Can downsizing with ImageMagick replace background colours/transparency with "guessed" adjacent colour?

Tags: command-line, imagemagick

I'm resizing sprites using ImageMagick that are an integer scale of their target dimensions (`240x240` -> `60x60`). The edges of the sprites become semi-transparent, which isn't perfect, but they still look good:

```
magick "sprite@4x.png" -filter cubic -define filter:b=0 -define filter:c=2.2 -define filter:blur=0.7 -resize 25% "sprite.png"
```

[image]

When resizing `.exr` files that contain depth information, the edges are blended with the background (black, as transparency results in heavy artifacts):

```
magick "sprite_depth@4x.exr" -background black -alpha remove -alpha deactivate -filter cubic -define exr:color-type=Y -resize 25% "sprite_depth.exr"
```

[image: Resizing .exr sprite]

As a result of the edge-blending/bleeding, the values around the edges are are much darker than they should be. (The cubic filter in the command is to try to more accurately match the regular sprites' results.)

I've read through the ImageMagick [Resize or Scaling](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/) page, however I couldn't find any information that helps fix my issue. I *believe* what I'm after is essentially extending the edges of the sprite out infinitely before resizing, so the downscaled edges aren't diluted:

[image]
*(Screenshot from [Crafting a Better Shader for Pixel Art Upscaling](https://youtu.be/d6tp43wZqps) by *t3ssel8r*.)*

Is this possible with ImageMagick? I'm also open to alternate suggestions to retain more accurate values around the edges.

Comment: The answer is in the page you link. Either `-adaptative-resize` or `-interpolative-resize` with `-interpolate Nearest`.

Comment: What about -sample or -magnify (pixel art scaling)

Comment: @xenoid The result still has some colour/transparency mixing in the downscale. [Here's](https://imgur.com/a/1WR45To) the result of using `magick from.png -interpolate nearest -interpolative-size 25% to.png`. I basically want those darker edge pixels to not become diluted by transparency. I don't suppose I'm missing another setting?

Comment: @fmw42 Surprisingly `-sample` actually yields similar results to the image I linked in my previous comment. As it picks the same pixel in the quadrant for each time, it also loses some pixels in areas where there should be some. An "intelligent" sample would be nice, though I can't seem to find any options for it! Hehe.

Comment: There is no "intelligent" resampling in Imagemagick the way you want it.